# When we move code between two variables then what will be happen to the variable between them

Tags: assembly, x86-16

I'm some confusion when I see the assembly code. Given below;

```
CURRENT_DOS_LOCATION DW 0000
FINAL_DOS_LOCATION DW 0000

INIT LABEL
SOME_VARIABLE
WRKSTK LABEL

ASSUME DS:SEG SYSINIT 
MOV AX, CS
ADD AX, BIOSSIZ
MOV DS:
[CURRENT_DOS_LOCATION], AX    

MOV AX,CS
ADD AX, ((OFFSET WRKSTK - 
OFFSET INIT) + 50) / 16

MOV DS:
[FINAL_DOS_LOCATION],AX
MOVSW
JMP SYSINIT
```

I have some confusion that when we move code or data between two labels then what will happen to the code between those labels.

here is some assembly code, I'm confused that when we move code between INIT and WRKSTK, then what will happen to the variable SOME_VARIABLE,is it will be needed, in this way we will lost completely, then what will happen if we need that variable in future in our code.

Comment: Can you please also post the modified code (the code after "moving" some lines of code) so that your question contains two parts of code?

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> INIT LABEL
> SOME_VARIABLE
> WRKSTK LABEL
> ```
>
> I'm confused that when we move code between INIT and WRKSTK, then what will happen to the variable SOME_VARIABLE

No matter what the "move" does, your program will always be able to address the *SOME_VARIABLE* variable simply because *SOME_VARIABLE* is but an address and that is invariable during your program's execution.
*You can't **loose** a variable*.

What can change is the memory contents found at the address specified by *SOME_VARIABLE*. This depends on the direction of the "move".

If your "move" had the memory range between *INIT* and *WRKSTK* as its source address then the variable in between them will remain intact.
If your "move" had the memory range between *INIT* and *WRKSTK* as its destination address then the variable in between them will get overwritten and very probably change value.

---

> ```
> MOVSW
> ```

This `movsw` instruction is the only instruction in your example that could maybe move from or to the range between *INIT* and *WRKSTK*. It will depend on the current setting of the registers `SI` and `DI`. You don't show what these registers contain!